# Customizing title and description of Swagger UI in Springfox

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

I intend to modify the title and description.
The method I discovered through online search involves using ApiInfoBuilder() to construct an ApiInfo, which is then passed to the Docket object.
Despite my attempts with numerous samples and variations, none of them have proven effective in my case.
My code is pretty straightforward

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableSwagger2

ApiInfo apiInfo =
                new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Demo Test API")
                        .description("Demo test API task")
                        .license("© 2021 by my")
                        .build();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.pachage.com"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
```

I'm using 3.0.0 version.

No matter which ApiInfoBuilder parameters gets, the title on the Swagger page remains unaffected.

[image]

Please advice, what I'm missing here.

Comment: Does the project use spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Swagger 3 (OpenAPI) but trying to configure Swagger 2.
To configure OpenAPI you need to provide `OpenAPI` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    OpenAPI api() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("title")
                        .description("description")
                        .license(new License()
                                .name("AGPLv3")
                                .url("https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html")));
    }
}
```